# How to get django context automatically in Jinja2 filters?

Tags: django, jinja2, django-context

For example, I have an paginator object with a lot of attributes, and don't want do write something like `{{ paginate(paginator) }}` in templates.

How can a get context automatically in the filter function, like a django `register.inclusion_tag(…, takes_context=True)`?

Yes, of course, I can do something like `paginate(paginator)`, but it looks weird, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, here it is.

```
@jinja2.contextfunction
def paginate(context):
    pass
```